# Ripple animation over image button difficulty

Tags: android, xml, material-design, android-animation, imagebutton

I am attempting to have a ripple effect play when a button is pressed, I have followed many guides on stack overflow and around the web but have not had any success. Can someone point me in the right direction? My XML looks to be correct but nothing happens when I click the button.

Thank you!

**Ripple_animation.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!-- thanks to http://www.viralandroid.com/2015/09/how-to-add-ripple-effect-to-android-button.html !-->

<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:color="@color/ripple_Orange"
    tools:targetApi="lollipop">
    <item android:id ="@android:id/mask">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color = "@color/ripple_Orange"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

</ripple>
```

**applying ripple effect to button**

```
 <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/one_button"
        android:background="@drawable/ripple_animation"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_width="85dp"
        android:layout_height="85dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/one_button_500_500"
        android:layout_below="@+id/four_button"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

Comment: The ripple is as background so the src is drawn on top. Try as foreground attribute or as foreground of a parent

Comment: @RobCo That worked, thank you! can you resubmit your response as an answer instead of a comment, I want to give you proper credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the ripple as the `background` attribute.
That means it is drawn behind the image src.

Instead, set it as the foreground of this view or it's parent:

```
android:foreground="@drawable/ripple_animation"
```

Answer (score 1):

**try this to show device default ripple effect**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:foreground="?android:selectableItemBackground">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/one_button"
            android:background="@drawable/ripple_animation"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_width="85dp"
            android:layout_height="85dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/one_button_500_500"
            android:layout_below="@+id/four_button"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
    </FrameLayout>
```